# Cannot find the class file for java.util.function.Consumer. Fix the build path then try building this project

Tags: java, eclipse

I am not at all using this java.util.function.Consumer class anywhere in my code.
I am using eclipse helios on ubuntu 14 and I have java-8-oracle installed. I suddenly ran into this problem, tried all the troubleshooting mentioned in SO but nothing works.

1. Tried closing reopening project
2. Tried removing and then adding JRE libraries
3. Tried Exporting importing project
4. Tried Source->cleanup
5. Tried setting -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
6. Tried restarting eclipse, rebooting machine.

Comment: I had to downgrade to java 7 and reinstall eclipse then it worked..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double check you Installed JREs preferences to have Java 8:
[Installed JREs prefs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUxRw.png)

Then check that you use 'compliance from execution environment 'JavaSE-1.8':
[Java Compiler prefs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGPfe.png)

Update:

You say you're using Eclipse Helios. It just doesn't support Java 8. All Java 8 APIs seem to be invisible for it. Your code obviously references some functional interfaces and thus doesn't compile.
Consider upgrading to Kepler, Luna or Mars.